# What is the purpose of setContentDescription() of a view?

Tags: android, android-view

I was in a dialemma on how to associate a string information to a view. I came across two methods

> setTag()

and

> setContentDescription()

Both served my purpose.

I know that setTag() is used in this cases generally. But when is setContentDescription() method used? , what is exact purpose of setContentDescription()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But when is setContentDescription() method used?

From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setContentDescription%28java.lang.CharSequence%29), `setContentDescription()` allows you to associate a textual description to the view.  The docs state that it's primarily used to support accessibility, so I assume it's there to support screen readers.

Comment: could you be more elaborate?, i did not get the accessibility and support screen readers parts.

Comment: this is for who can not ready in a good manner, so they are using some tools in the mobile device to let the mobile read the application screens for them.

search for accessibility word over the internet.

Answer (score 5):

Screen readers are used by those with impaired vision. “Accessibility” is a standard term for facilitating access by users with some kind of disability.